# PHP 7 Accelerator issue with Symfony 3

Tags: php, symfony, centos7, php-7

I have LEMP stack on CentOS 7, my lamp is using php 7 but after uploading symfony 3 project, I reffered to config.php from browser and it says that highly recommended to install PHP Accelerator.
okay, I'm typing yum install it says:

> Error: php70w-common conflicts with php-common-5.4.16-42.el7.x86_64
>    You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
>    You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest

what is the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My bet is that you're using an older guide. It's probably suggesting eAccelerator or the old PECL APC project. Both of these are opcode caches and both have been deprecated. It makes sense that trying to install either one would cause yum to try and install PHP 5.4

If you have the [Opcache package installed](http://php.net/manual/en/book.opcache.php) (typically `php-opcache` or similar) that's all you should need. It's built and maintained as part of the PHP core now (since PHP 5.5).